# Why am I getting `undefined` when trying to access array elements in Truffle Console?

Tags: contract-development, truffle, contract-debugging, arrays, truffle-console

I am getting an array from my contract, which seems to have the correct number of elements. However, when trying to access the first element using index notation, I am getting `undefined`:

```
myArray = myContract.getMyArray()
[
  BN {
    negative: 0,
    words: [ 0, <1 empty item> ],
    length: 1,
    red: null
  },
  BN {
    negative: 0,
    words: [ 0, <1 empty item> ],
    length: 1,
    red: null
  }
]

truffle(ganache)> myArray[0]
undefined
```

Any ideas why? I would have expected to get something like:

```
truffle(ganache)> myArray[0]
BN {
  negative: 0,
  words: [ 0, <1 empty item> ],
  length: 1,
  red: null
}
```

which I would then be able to convert to a number using the `.toNumber()` method and get `0`.

Additional info:
`myArray` is initialized as `myArray = new uint[](2);`. So I am expecting it should be initialized to `[0, 0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truffle functions return a `Future` so you need to await for the result:

```
> myArray = await myContract.getMyArray()

[
  BN {
    negative: 0,
    words: [ 0, <1 empty item> ],
    length: 1,
    red: null
  },
  BN {
    negative: 0,
    words: [ 0, <1 empty item> ],
    length: 1,
    red: null
  }
]

> myArray[0]

BN { negative: 0, words: [ 0, <1 empty item> ], length: 1, red: null }
```